# What's the policy on questions about TV shows still in progress?

Tags: discussion

We're getting a lot of "The Mandalorian" questions which is understandable but at the same time, it seems like one could broadly apply the "future-works" policy to either downvote or close questions that can reasonably be expected to be answered in later episodes at least (if not further seasons).

**Can / should we at least encourage questions to wait until the initial season is completed and *then* ask questions?**

(referencing The Mandalorian specifically, but more broadly looking towards ST: Picard coming next month as well which will likely cause the same phenomenon)

Comment: Very much depends on the question and how it’s worded. If it’s very likely to be answers in future episodes or if it asks about future episodes it’s close worthy else leave it be.

Comment: Basically the same policy we use for anything FW related

Comment: We also shouldn’t wait for a season to finish to ask questions. That would drive people away and lessen the traffic the site would get. Both being bad things.

Comment: Downvoting isn't much use in this case, closing is to be expected for anything already falling under future works.  I'm assuming the latest Q was downvoted for being obviously spoilery - if someone can actually point that or FW out to people asking, that would be more useful than a timed blanket ban.

Comment: The question titles should begin with "[SPOILERS]" as a given episode might not have been broadcast world-wide when a question is asked about it

Answer (score 10):

It may seem like a cliche response, but...

**Evaluate each question individually.**

We can not paint with a brush as broad as "Do not ask questions until the first season is over", especially since franchises like Star Wars, Star Trek, MCU (I am sure the new Marvel shows on Disney+ will generate questions in their first seasons), and many SFF titles in general have either been adapted, rebooted, or extended from novels, comic books, or previous TV series.

Many questions asked in the first season may be completely answered from extended lore or previous installments the OP is unaware of.

However as [I learned myself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223774/were-anakin-and-the-asset-in-the-mandalorian-born-in-the-same-year), asking about theories is going to get closed as Opinion Based per our [future works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based). (I was even to have mine reopened after focusing on something that is fact based).

Answer (score 0):

My general take on the [Future Works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/what-are-future-works) in this case is that there's a clear exception: works being published episodically (i.e. a TV series).

For instance [this question about Mandalorians and helmets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/223481/62709) got an accepted answer (derived from other canon works) before episode <s>IV</s> 4 aired and provided a direct answer. As long as we're not at a season break with questions clearly spanning into some yet-to-be made or published work, they should not be closed.

Comment: They shouldn't all be closed under the FWP but that doesn't mean none should either. There's a definite middle ground here.