# When are questions about characters in trailers Future Works?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, future-works

I just had [my question about the *Thor: Love and Thunder* trailer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262324/who-is-this-woman-wielding-mj%c3%b6lnir) downvoted into oblivion and closed. What's baffling is that it was closed as a "future work". From the [original meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187/62709)

> **BAD workflow - today:**
>
> 1. Question asked
> 2. **Question generates (likely) several bad opinion based answers. Some are upvoted**
> 3. Months/years later, correct canon answer is published
> 4. Someone answers with correct answer

I fully get that and support it. My general sense here is that **asking about key plot points before the work is release isn't useful**. In other words, you would need to **consume the story** to learn the answer.

My question isn't based on anything necessarily in the forthcoming movie itself. The character I wanted identified *has already been announced* and already exists elsewhere in Marvel canon (as evidenced by the highly objective answer). The fact that she's in the trailer at all was meant to tease her but I didn't recognize her. Similar questions have not faced this same treatment

- [Who is this character in the second Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice trailer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109452/who-is-this-character-in-the-second-batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice-trailer)
- [Who is this half Thor, half Iron Man dude in the Spider-Man: Far From Home trailer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203507/who-is-this-half-thor-half-iron-man-dude-in-the-spider-man-far-from-home-trail)
- [What was that big toothy inter-dimensional creature in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158555/what-was-that-big-toothy-inter-dimensional-creature-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy-v)

We're not consistent here *at all*. Some questions get closed, some do not. And even if the question has an objective answer it still gets closed?

What exactly is the standard here?

Comment: To be honest this seems like one of those where it will have to be case by case basis. Sometimes information exists from press releases and other media (comics, for example) and sometimes it doesn't. In either case these are all going to be in a grey area.

Comment: I voted to close because, following by the letter, it's a question about an unreleased work. Is that really Jane Foster? Or is it actually _Fane Joster_, an evil clone from another dimension? We won't know for sure until the movie is released. Hyperbole aside, I can see in this case it was the wrong vote to cast

Comment: It doesn't make it a good question. If you'd make a Q&A, self-answering, just after asking, then OK, but in this case, the downvotes aren't unearned and you were very much tempting CVters... But I checked and it was quickly answered, so that's kinda weird.

Comment: @Mithoron And what makes it a poor question? How did I "tempt [close voters]"?

Comment: @Mithoron Machavity pointed out not knowing the answer. That would make self-answering very difficult.

Comment: What I find extremely strange though is how another question about that trailer was much better received and even became a HNQ, and it also was a character identification question.

Comment: @Clockwork I think the community learnt from the previous question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### This question was wrongly closed

*I almost closed it too*.

I literally clicked on the title expecting to need to close it, saw the answer and realised **it wasn't future works.**

The question could have done with an indication why you thought it wasn't future works, but honestly it doesn't seem closeworthy to me.

It's open now, happy to discuss here or chat if people disagree.

Answer (score 8):

### Case-by-Case Basis

[Note: while AncientSwordRage has addressed the single question the, I am answering in the broader sense as I think was the OP's intent.]

The problem with trailers is, like you said:

> The fact that she's in the trailer at all was meant to tease her...

There are tons of teases in every trailer, and sometimes that doesn't make it into the final product. Films may go through reshoots, recasting, etc. They may also be intentionally misleading. This creates quite a flux state of what we can determine from a trailer.

In-line with the general ["future-works policy"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11865/57310) questions about a trailer would need to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis and ask ourselves:

> Is there established canon that would be able to answer this question without any information from the future work?

If yes, then the question is not future works. If no, then the question is future works. If the trailer pulled a fast one the answer can always be updated later...

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, movies release trailers that don't contain scenes that make it into the final movie (the final scene in [this *Men in Black* trailer](https://youtu.be/HYUd7AOw_lk?t=132) was not in the movie). My frustration here comes more from sheer inconsistency. Since I posted this Meta, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262344) about the same trailer has been readily accepted by the community even though it is asking what (according to this answer) should have been closed. It's not clear at all what the difference is.

Comment: @Machavity it's probably a good thing that the community learnt from it's mistake with your question and is not reacting in the same way. I've bountied it and edited so people can reverse their downvotes

Comment: @AncientSwordRage That may have had more to do with asking about an existing character with a lot of publicity around their return vs a new character that just happened to match 1 to 1 a panel from a comic.